# Magento : How To Add an Attribute to Static Block

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, custom-attributes, cms-block

How to add attribute to static block. I am not looking for code, but also where put code.
Assume attribute is named `test` and static block name `sttest`.
I have search on this, but always get lost on where to add that code.

Thanks

Comment: specify your magento version.

Comment: Also which type of attribute you need to display

Comment: Let me explain what I’m trying to accomplish. I’m using Magento ver. 1.9.1.0. I want to add a CMS block tab on my product pages. I know how to create a block, and how to add that block to a product pages. The problem is getting the block to show what I want it to. I want to have the block to show the information of an attribute. I understand the code you just provided should be in the block, but that alone is not the only changes that need to be made …right? What else must be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **block** in any of your module and in its corresponding **template** file you may add/print the attribute **test** and then call that block in your static pages/block **sttest**.

```
{{block class="Vendor\Module\Block\MyBlock" name="testblock" template="attributetest.phtml"}}
```

You may call the block as mentioned above in your static block in admin area. All you need to do is place this line of code in the content of your static block.

I hope this helps you. Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Let me explain what I’m trying to accomplish.  I’m using Magento ver. 1.9.1.0.  I want to add a CMS block tab on my product pages.  I know how to create a block, and how to add that block to a product pages.  The problem is getting the block to show what I want it to.  I want to have the block to show the information of an attribute.
I understand the code you just provided should be in the block, but that alone is not the only changes that need to be made …right?  What else must be done?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace every instance of $this->getProduct() with `Mage::registry('current_product') inside description.phtml.`

Alternative (somewhat cleaner): Make this your first line in `description.phtml: <?php $this->setProduct(Mage::registry('current_product')) ?>`